# dividing a network into a grid of small cells in a SUMO scenario

Tags: sumo

Is there a way to divide an already- existing road network into a 2-D grid of equal sized cells?
I need to extract some information such as vehicle density, average speed,...etc. from each cell.

are there any libraries, tools, APIs or tutorials?
I am new to SUMO so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to generate an [fcd output](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Output/FCDOutput) (`sumo --fcd-output`) which gives coordinates for every vehicle and then aggregate the values in a simple script. Depending on the precision needed and the data volume you expect, you can also aggregate the output to edges (and to time intervals) in SUMO using the [mean data output](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Output/Lane-_or_Edge-based_Traffic_Measures) but then you will need to handle the case of edges which are in multiple cells yourself. There is some help in parsing a sumo network and sumo outputs in [sumolib](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tools/Sumolib).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually this is not only the reason why i need to divide the map into grid. I have to import it to another simulation tool and place some communication nodes in each cell based on this data. That why i have o divide it into cells or zones. Do you know how?